# _mydatePicker.enabled = FALSE; prevents datepicker movement in iOS 6 but not iOS 7

Tags: ios7, xcode5

In viewDidAppear I have set _mydatePicker.enabled =FALSE.  This "freezes" the date picker and does not respond to touch when used in iOS 6;  However in iOS 7 the date picker wheel continues to be able to be turned by the user. Is there a way of "freezing" the datepicker wheel unless _mydatPicker.enabled =TRUE is called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use :

```
datePicker.userInteractionEnabled = FALSE;
```

It will work in iOS 7 or iOS 6.

Answer (score 1):

How about using the userInteractionEnabled property?